# Eye-tracking analysis: proportion, looking time... or both?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model

I am using mixed-effects models to analyse some eye-tracking data. I know that people typically use either total looking time at an Area of Interest (AOI) or proportion of looking time at an AOI (usually computed as looking time to that AOI divided by looking time to all AOIs).

Which one is the most informative is a quite hot debate, and I was wondering if it would make sense to just use both? I think that mathematically it would make sense, but I wonder what people think about the validity of it, and how people would implement it. I would go around doing this like that for example:

```
PropAOI1 ~ Condition + LookingTimeAllAOI + Condition:LookingTimeAllAOI
```

where condition is whatever main manipulation I am doing, usually between-subjects.

**Edit:** in my research I'm only interested in two AOIs, and so analysing data for one of them is enough. However in the more general case where we have more than one AOI, one could have `AOI` and `Prop` as two separate columns, then do something like:

```
Prop ~ Condition*AOI*TotalLookingTime
```

I'm keeping those equations as basic as possible to just show the general structure of the model, but it would often be a regression or a mixed-effects model with random interecepts and slopes by participant (`1 + AOI + TotalLookingTime | Participant` as `Condition` is between-subject).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you are really trying to figure out and what the research participants are instructed to do. Having said that:

1. There is a third possibility, which involves analyzing simultaneously the looking times (or proportions of looking times) for all AOIs;
2. The formula you provided is incomplete, as you haven't mentioned what family of models  you are going to use (e.g., mixed effects beta regression models?), so it could do with some clarification.

You should start by clarifying whether there is a known hierarchy of "importance" between the AOIs involved in your study.

If there is, is one of the AOIs more "important" than all others and are the participants instructed/directed to spend most of their looking time on that area?

If there isn't, are you just trying to figure out an hierarchy of "importance" among AOIs and hoping to use the looking times (or proportion of looking times) to uncover it?

What does looking time at an AOI tell us about that AOI? Is it true that the longer one looks at that AOI, the more "important" that AOI is? (I am using the metric of "importance" for an AOI as I am not familiar with your area of research - there may be other metrics that better capture the meaning of looking time.)

If you consider looking time for a specific LOI, that seems to imply that you care about a single AOI at the time. (In other words, that AOI exists in a vacuum.)

If you consider proportion of looking time for a specific AOI relative to looking times across all AOIs, that seems to imply that you care about that specific AOI as it relates to all others. (In other words, that AOI is one of several AOIs in a system of possibly inter-related AOIs.)

Could you look at both types of outcomes: looking time versus proportion of looking times? Certainly, as long as you are clear about what research question is targeted by each outcome and what paradigm of "importance" (or other relevant metric) underlies your use of each outcome.

Note that I am coming at your question from a common-sense approach, hoping these thoughts will help you make inroads in addressing your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I was trying to make this as general as possible, but in my case I only have two AOIs and so if we ignore looks outside of AOIs then analysing only one gives us all the information. The main problem is that it's not clear in the field what measure is the best, or even what each measure really means, and so my aim was to try and come up with an analysis that deals with this question in a principled way. But you talking about analysing all AOIs together actually made me realise another (better?) way of doing this!

Comment: That's great, Arthur! Sometimes people keep perpetuating confusion in a field, which doesn't mean you have to do the same.  Addressing your problem in a principled, defensible way which reflects the specifics of your own situation - rather than the generalities of the field - is the best you can do.